# How to recode variables with NA?

Tags: r

I want to reprogram variables `D2` to `D3` in the following data-frame

```
    D1          D2          D3
[1] Yes    0-15 MINUTES    7.5
[2] Yes    15-30 MINUTES   22.5
[3] Yes    30-60 MINUTES   45
[4] Yes       NA           NA
[5] NEVER     NA           0
```

Basically, it is converting `D2` to its numerical midpoint. However, `D2` could be NA.

1. If `D1 = "Yes"` and `D2` is `NA`, then `D3` should remain `NA`
2. If `D1 = "NEVER"`, `D2` is always `NA` and `D3` should be `0`.

Here is my attempt:

```
library(plyr)

data$D3 <- revalue(data$D2, c(
"0-15 MINUTES" = "7.5",
"15-30 MINUTES" = "22.5",
"30-60 MINUTES" = "45")) //this part works perfectly fine
```

However, when trying to convert the `NA` to `0` due to `D1` being `"NEVER"`, I encounter the following error:

```
data$D3 [data$D1 == "NEVER"] <- 0

Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, data$D1 == "NEVER", value = c(2L, 2L, 3L,  :
invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Comment: This isn't a bug, the problem is that your `D1` column is factor, not character.  You may "fix" this by just using `as.character(data$D1)` in place of what you currently have.  A better long term solution might be to create your data frame with `stringsAsFactors` set to false.

Comment: That printing looks like a weird matrix/data.frame cross. As Tim alluded, the error is a product of how you're inputting your data.

Answer (score 0):

```
x%>%extract(D2,c("y","n"),"(\\d+)-(\\d+)")%>%
    mutate(D3=(as.numeric(y)+as.numeric(n))/2)
     D1    y    n   D3
1   Yes    0   15  7.5
2   Yes   15   30 22.5
3   Yes   30   60 45.0
4   Yes <NA> <NA>   NA
5 NEVER <NA> <NA>   NA
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
df=tibble(D1=c("YES","YES","YES","YES","NEVER"),D2=c("0-15 MINUTES","15-30 MINUTES","30- 60 MINUTES",NA,NA))
y=df$D2%>%str_replace("MINUTES","")%>%str_split("-")%>%unlist%>%na.omit%>%as.numeric%>%rollapply(FUN=mean,width=2,by=2)
df$D3=NA
df$D3[!is.na(df$D2)]=y
df$D3[is.na(df$D2)&df$D1=="NEVER"]=0
```